# ASP.Net Kestrel not loading up console from Visual Studio, how can I debug the issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm  trying to debug why my ASP.Net RC-1 project isn't running on Kestrel. When I hit 'web' as the startup option, the output window seems clean - there's no exceptions. But the console that I'm told will pop up - doesn't. How can I debug what is causing this issue?

I created another template project and ran that just to make sure that ran ok from Kestrel and it did.

These are the last lines of the output, for my project:

```
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\David\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices: Information: User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0xf80 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7ec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3f38 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x10d4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

**EDIT:**

I should add, it runs just fine on IIS.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I debug what is causing this issue?

We can troubleshoot the issue; unfortunately, we cannot debug it. Here is a first troubleshooting step.

Open a command prompt. Then `cd` to the directory that contains the project.json file. Then run the following commands. This will give you some more information.

```
C:\MyProject>  dnu restore
C:\MyProject>  dnu build
C:\MyProject>  dnx web
```

The above restores NuGet packages, builds the project, and runs the `web` command. If it works from the command line, then something is going wrong specifically in Visual Studio.

Comment: This is possibly the most well written response I have ever received on stack overflow, it was perfectly levelled, and very informative - so sincerely, thank you. 
It turns out that my build on Web was not set to debug and so my user-secrets weren't getting populated in to the configuration builder, thus causing the issue. I have now fixed the problem.

Comment: I should add, that the dnx web from the command line was where I discovered the exception. For some reason this wasn't visible from inside of visual studio.